# Is it necessary to have a local base branch checkout when committing changes?

Tags: git, gitlab

In the structure below, I have a branch named **master ---> branches/setupServicePI5 —> FLT 01**
Will it work if I delete branches/setupServicePI5 from local and then commit while updating FLT 01? Is it necessary to keep branches/setupServicePI5 updated locally?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can delete **branches/setupServicePI5**, and it won't affect **FTL 01**. Each commit knows it's parent (or parents, in the case of a merge commit). A branch just keeps track of the top commit on that branch, and so it can trace itself all the way back to master when you need to merge it!

Than being said, if there are any commits on **branches/setupServicePI5** that *aren't* in **FTL 01**, those will be deleted. You can check if that's the case by running

```
git log 'FTL 01..branches/setupServicePI5'
```

This will list all the commits on **branches/setupServicePI5** that *aren't* on **FTL 01**. If it's empty, then it's safe to delete **branches/setupServicePI5** since all of it's commits are on **FTL 01**.

If commits do exist that aren't on **FTL 01**, and you want to view the contents of those commits, you can use patch view, which will show the changes made in each commit:

```
git log --patch 'FTL 01..branches/setupServicePI5'
```